# Solving a system of nonlinear equations in python

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, nonlinear-functions

I have a homework which requires to solve this system of equations:

[image]

So my variables are:

[image]

So I have N-1 equations and N-1 variables. I am supposed to solve it in Python using the scipy.optimize library, but I am not very good in programming and I got stuck. My code looks like this: (N=500 btw)

```
def fun(x, F):
    for j in range(1000):
        if j < N:
            return F[j + 1] * (x[j] - x[j + 1]) + F[j + 2] * (x[j + 2] - x[j + 1]
        else:
            return -F[j + 1] * np.sqrt(l ** 2 - (x[j + 1] - x[j + 1]) ** 2) + F[j + 2] * np.sqrt(l ** 2 - (x[j + 2] - x[j + 1]) ** 2) - m * g * l
prom = scipy.optimize.root(fun, (x0, f0))
```

And I am getting this error:

> TypeError: fun() missing 1 required positional argument: 'F'

The thing is I don't really know how to use the scipy function, but I tried creating an array of my equations and I have an initial guess in variables x<sub>0</sub> and F<sub>0</sub>. So I would like to ask if my function actually corresponds to my equations, I mean if I programmed correctly using the cycle or I should use something else. And also if I am successful in creating the function corresponding to my system of equations, how do I use scipy to solve it? What arguments should I put in?

Comment: You will have to provide more context (and copy-paste the code). So there are a thousand F's?

Comment: It is a numerical solution to a physics problem so there should be infinitely many F´s because the equations are an aproximation and I chose 1000 points as the aproximation. I am just interested how the arguments of scipy.optimize.roots work I checked the library page but I am not a programmer so I didnt understand it.

Comment: You vector of variables has 1,000 elements. This implies that the function you send to scipy.optimize.root as its first argument will have a *single*-argument vector of length 1000.

Comment: Apparently there are two parameters, namely x0 and F0. This implies that the second argument to the scipy function should be a vector-like object of length two.

Comment: And I almost forgot that your *fun* will need two arguments, the first the aforementioned 1000-element vector of variables and the second the two-element vector of trial values of x0 and F0.

Comment: One more thing: I find it very helpful when people like you post the mathematical representations of problems, as you have done. However, it would be better if you could post your code in text form.

Comment: It wasn't necessary to post the whole thing as an image. You should have posted only the equations as images and the rest as plain text or code.